# asp.net mvc ¿por que no puedo crear una Session[" "] en una clase?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

me encuentro con una gran incógnita y es que no me deja crear una `Session[""]` en un archivo de clase solo en un archivo de controlador.

Alguien sabe a que se debe esto o como podría crear una ahí?

Comment: ¿En una clase? ¿Cuál clase? ¿Cómo intentas acceder a `Session[""]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deberias definir el using a `System.Web` y usar

```
HttpContext.Current.Session[]
```

la pagina web hereda de Page por eso puede acceder directo al objeto Session, en cambio una clase no lo hace.

Si esa clase ejecuta dentro de un ambiente web podria acceder a los objetos por medio de `HttpContext.Current`

[What is the difference between these two HttpContext.Current.Session and Session - asp.net 4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7954844/what-is-the-difference-between-these-two-httpcontext-current-session-and-session)

Comment: precisamente venia a responder esto

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta.